# Legend loses second artist when I move it outside plot

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

When I add a second data series to my plot (with a secondary y-axis) and attempt to move the legend, I lose the reference to the second series.  It works if I don't try to move the legend location, but optimally I'd like to place the legend outside the plot.  Is there a quick fix for this?

This has both series labels in the legend:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0,100,1)
y1 = x
y2 = x**2

tempDF = pd.DataFrame({'y1': y1, 'y2': y2}, index=x)

ax = tempDF.plot(y='y1')
tempDF.plot(y='y2', ax=ax, secondary_y=True)
```

[Default behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imoWm.png)

When I add the following code to move the legend I lose the second series label:

```
ax.legend(loc=(1.15,.9))
```

[Legend loses second series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfZtX.png)

Is there an easy fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you may of course add a legend for each axes,

```
ax = tempDF.plot(y='y1')
ax2 = tempDF.plot(y='y2', ax=ax, secondary_y=True)

ax.legend(loc=(0.9,.9))
ax2.legend(loc=(0.9,.8))
```

To have both inside the same legend, you may create the legend from the respective legend handles and labels,

```
ax = tempDF.plot(y='y1')
ax2 = tempDF.plot(y='y2', ax=ax, secondary_y=True)

h1, l1 = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
h2, l2 = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(h1+h2, l1+l2, loc=(0.9,.9))
```

An alternative is to use a figure legend.

```
ax = tempDF.plot(y='y1')
tempDF.plot(y='y2', ax=ax, secondary_y=True)

ax.figure.legend(loc=(0.9,.9))
```

Note that this figure legend may only work in newer matplotlib versions. Also note that the coordinates for `loc` are now figure coordinates instead of axes coordinates.

Comment: That works - thank you!  I tried the figure legend but I'm currently relegated to a very old version of matplotlib.